# Add -fobjc-arc flag to new files created in Xcode automatically

Tags: xcode, target, compiler-flags

I have an iOS project that uses MRC, but for new source code I want to use ARC. How can I set up the project so that it will add the `-fobjc-arc` flag for each new file?

Even better would be to set it separately for particular targets, because this project has 17 targets, of which **10 use MRC** and **7 use ARC**. Is there some possibility to set up file creation by target, so that those which use MRC, will have the flag added?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want all new files to be ARC and all existing files to be MRC, it seems it would be easier to flag all existing files with `-fno-objc-arc` and change the target to be an ARC target. Then all new files will be ARC by default.

Comment: good idea, but unfortunatelly now we have 487 files and about half of it is "pre ARC" files. Maybe we can use some script to remove -fobjc-arc flag from those which does have it and add -fno-objc-arc flag to those which don't and then switch to ARC.

Comment: View the list of files in the Build Phases tab of the target. Multi-select all of the files you need to change. Change one file. The change will be applied to all of the selected files. Quick and simple.